# Accessing home directory with `base` in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob

I am trying to copy selected files from my home directory using Gulp but the following does not do it:

```
var files = ['one', 'two'];
gulp.task('collect', function(){
  return gulp.src(files, {base: '~/'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

What is the correct setting for the `base` to make it work?
[The Docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) is very terse on this.

Comment: try `{base: '.'}`, thats what I use

Comment: @entre not enough - files not copied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the home directory use the `user-home` package (see https://github.com/sindresorhus/user-home) or when using Node >= 4.0 then you can also use [os.homedir()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir). In Node >= 4.0:

```
var os = require('os'),
    path = require('path');
var files = ['one', 'two'];
var homeDir = os.homedir();

gulp.task('collect', function(){
    return gulp.src(files.map(x => path.join(homeDir, x)),
            {base: homeDir})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for `os.homedir()`! Seems like `base` applies to where files are moved, not where they to be found. Have to manually prefix files at the run time.

Comment: Then just use `return gulp.src(files.map(x => path.join(os.homedir(), x)), {base: os.homedir()}).`

Comment: When I add `base`, my files go into same-named subdirectories inside, which is not intuitive, I wish I understand it better.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what would you like to achieve. You have two files, named `one` and `two` in your home directory. According to your question you want to copy them to the directory where the Gulpfile resides. The current answer does exactly that.

Comment: It does indeed. I am just trying to understand the role of `base` in there --- is there any need for it?

Comment: You are right, it does not required in this context. You can override the default value generated by glob2base from your paths when generating destination paths. For example if you use root for base, the whole folder structure including 'home/username' will be created inside the destination directory and files will be copied there. See: https://github.com/contra/glob2base